# In which situations I cannot include isolated mine to a 8 power federation even though then I can't create a federation at all?

Tags: gaia-project

The [rule book](https://howdoyouplayit.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Gaia-Project-Rules.pdf) of Gaia Project says that:

- you can choose planets that are farther away, **as long as those
  planets are needed** to have a total power value of at least seven
- You cannot form a federation by connecting more planets
  and satellites than are needed to form it

the key word is "need" and it is unclear what is behind this word. My question is:

**Are there situations, in which I cannot include isolated mine to a 8 power federation even though otherwise I can't create a federation at all?**

Here are a few examples:

1. Let's say I have three separate clusters of buildings with power 4 (2xTrading station), 3 (PI), 1 (mine). In general I can not create federation of them, since it would be 8 power and 7 power is possible by excluding one cluster (mine).

[image]

But what if the mine is in-between 4-power cluster and PI and is surrounded by my federations already, so there is no way to connect 4-power cluster with PI with out touching mine with my satellites. So I have only three options:

a) create a federation of 8-power including the mine

b) do not create the federation at all

c) develop mine into a 4-power cluster by building another building nearby and create a federation ignoring 2 trading stations below it.

can one say here that I do need to include the mine "to have a total power value of at least seven"?

2. The very similar situation, but the mine can not be developed into 4-power cluster, so option c) is not an option I either create the 8-power federation or can not create the federation at all.
   [image]
   Is here my "need" considered to be enough?
3. Another situation, when there is a path to connect 2 trading stations with PI with out a mine, but it requires 24 satellites, and I have only 3 power tokens, so I can not do it right away. Is here my "need" considered to be enough to include the mine?
   [image]
4. The same situation as in ex.3, but it is the end of the game, and I don't have resources for sure to get 24 satellites. Is here my "need" considered to be enough?

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, there is only one question - "Are there situations, in which I cannot include isolated mine to a 8 power federation even though otherwise I can't create a federation at all?" The rest are just examples to clarify it. All I do is clarifying the rule of the game, it would be weird to split it to several topics. I've added pictures to illustrate my doubts.

Comment: When I read this question I see at least 4 different questions being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the exact process of forming a federation is this:

1. Choose structures with a combined power level of at least 7 that are not already part of a federation. (I will call the federation that you are trying to form the *forming federation*.)
2. Connect the structures of the forming federation by placing as few satellites as possible.

   - You must take detours when needed to avoid touching existing federations of yours.
   - You must include additional structures (that are not already part of a federation) if doing so allows you to use fewer satellites.

   If there are several ways of doing so, you can choose how to do it, even if those ways have different power levels.
3. If you could now remove **both** at least one of your satellites **and** one of your structures from the forming federation without falling below the combined power level of 7 nor disconnecting the forming federation, you cannot form that federation. (But you can form one by choosing different structures in step 1, in this case.)

In particular, the need to use as few satellites as possible (for the chosen structures!) is very strong, and it is fine if that means including an additional mine, for example. (Look at the example on page 15.)

So in your examples, you can always form the federation and you always must do so by including the mine in the middle an placing three satellites.

(This follows the official FAQ linked to in the comments by the OP: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2120375/official-federation-faq.)

Comment: Do you have any source to back it up?

Comment: I will try to come back to this later, but the most important source is the example on page 15: Notice how they say that it is fine to include the additional mine (even though it’s not needed for the power level) because both federations require the same number of satellites and the bigger federation would fall apart if you removed both a satellite and a structure.

Comment: (When they talk about removing a structure and satellite, they mean removing them *without* moving anything else.)

Comment: Last point for now: I have some experience with the game on BoardGameArena (which has official licenses for its games) and it works like this on that site.

Comment: I've found official faq, which is very similar to your answer. If you modify your answer to include it I will accept it. https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2120375/official-federation-faq

Comment: Actually, the official FAQ differs from my understanding. (I used to think that taking detours to avoid touching existing federations was illegal, but apparently it’s not.) I changed my answer to reflect that.